# JavaScript / JQuery display image instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have a JS method which I pass in a number of parameters, one newText, which sets the text to be displayed on my page. The problem I have is that I want to display an image instead of text. I've tried a number of approaches but I either have the textual output displayed (i.e. img src=""....) or a HTMLImage object tag displayed. Does anyone know how I can modify the middleTextTop.text(newText) so that I can either pass in HTML code? I have already tried $.parseHTML( str ) which doesn't want to work.

Thanks in advance of any help.

```
middleTextTop   
    /*Current text disappear*/
    .transition().delay(700 * delayDisappear).duration(700)
    .attr('opacity', 0) 
    /*New text appear*/
    .call(endall,  function() {
        middleTextTop.text(newText)
        .attr("y", -24*loc + "px")
        .attr("x", xloc + "px")
        .call(wrap, w); 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
middleTextTop.html(newText)
```

instead of

```
middleTextTop.text(newText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
middleTextTop.text(newText)
```

call

```
$img = $("img").prop('src', 'http://image-src/');
middleTextTop.append($img);
```

(You could also .html() the img tag, but DOM-lego isn't a good practice).